# Poco create HTTPServerRequest object for unit test

Tags: poco-libraries

I'm writing unit test for my application which has a following function

std:: string getHandler(HTTPServerRequest& request){
}

I'm facing the problem in creating HTTPServerRequest object as it is Abstract class & its subclasd needs HTTPServerRequestImpl requires creation of HTTP Server & a request.

Any help towards simplifying creation of HTTPServerRequest object would be highly appreciated

Comment: If you do not want to use HTTPServerRequestImpl, you will obviously have to create your own stripped-down version and pass it in. Implementation details depend on what exactly you are trying to test, which is not entirely clear from the post.

Comment: @Alex Used my custom implementation. It workd. Thnx